# laravel blade template and vue.js spot combination for layout

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

up untill now i used the blade template for making my master layout and i used to make some thing like this code in my layout.blade.php

```
<div class="m-grid__item m-grid__item--fluid m-wrapper">
        @yield('content')
    </div>
```

and some thing like this in every other file that i wanted

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="m-subheader ">


    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
...
```

and i made a layout for my admin panel for example but now that i want to use vue.js i want to know how can i make a master template and include other sections and parts and the more important question is should i do it at all or no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Vue JS components anywhere in your blade layouts.

There is a good example of how to integrate Vue JS components into your Laravel frontend in the Laravel documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend

Read the section titled: "Writing Vue Components"

Comment: ok thanks that's the answer !!! i Haven't seen that part i don't know why :)  so know for example i have added metronic admin panel theme and added vue to laravel but then all the jquery events and functions like dropdown menu not working any idea how to fix some sort of problems ?